# Common solution for sending an email with image for Outlook and Gmail

Tags: node.js, outlook, gmail, html-email, amazon-ses

I tried to send simple HTML template with an image tag to users email using Amazon SES.

- When I try to add s3 bucket URL as the image, Outlook blocks the image and marks it as junk mail.
- However, when I try to send email using embedded images(base64 URL), Gmail blocks the content.

On looking for a solution, I found that we can send images using content-id (first we need to attach the image in email, then use attachment name as CID). But doing it this way will also show the attachment in email which will be ugly.

Is there any way to send HTML template with image URL (not as an attachment) that should work in all email providers like Gmail, Outlook and IOS email?

Answer (score 0):

> I found that we can send images using content-id (first we need to attach the image in email, then use attachment name as CID). But doing it this way will also show the attachment in email which will be ugly.

In Outlook you could set up a low-level property `PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN` which indicates *whether an attachment is hidden from the end user*. Theoretically, the value should be translated to the MIME header, so you may try to set this property in Outlook for attachments and then check the internet header values on the recipient side. For example, in Outlook VBA you could do the following:

```
Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B"

Dim myAtt As Attachment
Dim pa As propertyAccessor
Dim bHidden As Boolean

For Each myAtt In Item.Attachments

    Debug.Print myAtt.DisplayName
    
    Set pa = myAtt.propertyAccessor
        
    bHidden = False
    
    On Error Resume Next
    bHidden = pa.GetProperty(PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN)
    If err <> 0 Then bHidden = True ' Set True when property not found
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook always 'blocks' images by default (click to download). This is how the email software works, like several other email clients. Hosting on something like s3 or similar is the right/normal way.

Using CID will also massively inflate the size of the email, which has serious issues, and it probably won't forward well either.

So always use the standard img with src to a public host: `<img src="https://www.imageserver.com/path" ...>`

Comment: okay then how can i send images in email templates? i should send images in email templates somehow

Comment: I updated the answer - thought you had this already?